# Bios update says ROM file does not match (BIOSTAR X370GT7)

Tags: motherboard, bios, amd-ryzen

I'm trying to upgrade from Ryzen 1600 to 3600.
When I put new 3600 CPU into my MB - it fails to even show post screen.

My MB is: Biostar X370GT7

My current BIOS is X37AG314, which is relatively old, 03/14/17
When I use Biostar BiosUpdate: the Utility shows my current BIOS and says **its latest**.

However, on the website for the motherboard I see many newer versions (https://www.biostar.com.tw/app/en/mb/introduction.php?S_ID=874#download). And I see users on some forums mention those older BIOS on their X370GT7.

So I went ahead and downloaded couple latest versions, but when I try to install them, the flasher says:

> WARNING!!!
> The ROM file information does not match with the system BIOS!
> If forcedly update BIOS, it may destroy the system BIOS!
> We strongly do not suggest to flash the BIOS!

Does it mean I will brick my MB if I go ahead? Or it happens when there is a big difference between versions?
How to proceed with CPU upgrade?

P.S. Biostar CPU support info on official website does look that accurate. They declare Ryzen 1600 support since ver. X37AG623.BST. But that version is 3 months newer than my current BIOS. And I have no issues with Ryzen 1600.

UPDATE:

By doing incremental updates I was able to go few versions up till
X37AG919.BST. It is still rather old - end of 2017.

Next version gives me same warning as before.

UPDATE:

my MB turned out to have backup ROM. So in case of a problem i should be able to boot from backup. So I went ahead and re-flashed straight to the version that supports new CPU. It worked.

Comment: do you have version 5 of the motherboard?  If not, you probably don't have the correct BIOS version

Comment: I have some early version... I bought it 4 years back. But their website does not show other versions of MB.

Comment: What Operating system?

Comment: I suggest you upgrade the bios one step at a time, jumping from that old bios version to the latest version may not work, upgrade one version higher at a time.

Comment: the OS is windows 10 x64

Comment: @Moab - that approach worked for a bit.. I was able to upgrade 3 vers up to X37AG919.BST. But now it is stuck... same message for the next version

Comment: Have you tried the cpu again?

Comment: The 3600 worked eventually, but only on two latest BIOS. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the answer depends on the fact if MB has backup BIOS ROM. My Mb has one. In this case reflashing issue would not necessary brick your MB. You can switch to backup and use it and even reflash primary ROM to original version.

If you MB **does not** have backup ROM - follow @John answer and contact your manufacturer support.

If you MB has backup ROM - go ahead and try. It worked for me just fine. And the 3600 CPU got recognized only on those latest versions. Intermediate versions did not work, even though website declared support.

Answer (score 2):

I would very definitely obey the warning and not force BIOS update with the wrong version.

Your machine may have numerous sub-models with different BIOS versions (not uncommon).

Since you do not know (other forums) what minor model difference other users have, that experience is not necessarily relevant.

Do not update if the BIOS says No.

That means reverting to the prior CPU.

Comment: i did revert to write this question :)  But how to upgrade now?

Comment: As @John states, you *might* brick your PC by forcing the update. Contact the motherboard's manufacturer for help, and if the online support is insufficient, phone for help: https://www.biostar-usa.com/contactus.asp and try to get an email from them stating the correct procedure, so if damage is done, they have responsibility.

Comment: yep, just send them a question online